# running JUnit or testng TC on AIX

Tags: java, junit, testng

The test below runs with no issue as testng TC in my `Eclipse` Env. I couldn’t find a way to run it as testng TC on `AIX` env, so I tried to run it as JUnit TC using JUnit runner.
But, I get the error below `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods`

The `testGetRatePlan()` (code shown below) has the `@Test` annotation, with the enable parameter set to true. I also tried it without `enabled = true` and still same issue.

Any recommendation how else I should run it?

Thanks!

run.sh script has the below options:

```
/usr/java6_64/bin/java $jopts -cp junit-4.9.jar:contiperf.jar:bcs_app_bb.jar:bcs_app_bb_test.jar:testng.jar:jmock.jar:bcs_app_bb.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.cvp.prp.PRPBuildingBlockTest

ms21cp01> run.sh    JUnit version 4.9 .E Time: 0.003 There was 1 failure: 1) initializationError(com.cvp.prp.PRPBuildingBlockTest) java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:157)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:336)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
        at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
        at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:69)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:98)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:53)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:45)

FAILURES!!! Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

****The code:****

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public void testGetRatePlan() throws Throwable {
    readRecord(ACCOUNT_WITH_SUBSC_V1);
    final PrpSubscriptionRecord expectedSubscription = prepareTestOutput();

    expect(new Expectations() {
        {
            oneOf(enablerMock).get(PrpDAO.class);
            will(returnValue(prpDAOMock));

            oneOf(prpDAOMock).getSubscription(subscriptionId);
            will(returnValue(expectedSubscription));
        }
    });

    String actualRatePlan = prpBBimpl.getRatePlan(transData, tgc, callType);

    Assert.assertEquals(actualRatePlan, promotionName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JUnit annotations if you want to run a JUnit test.

Besides that, I have no idea what "TC" means.

Comment: You mean he imported '@Test' from testng but needs to import '@Test' from junit?

Comment: Yes. If the annotation works with one test framework, it won't work with the other.

Answer (score 0):

change the annotation as well as Imports from testNg to junit. also change your sh file to use junit runner.